# Testing django_openid_provider

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm using django-openid-provider (https://bitbucket.org/romke/django_openid_provider/) and need to test it's features before deploying on a real server. I've tried to construct POST request by documentation of OpenID 2.0 and send it to django's test server to get openid token.

My post looks like so:

```
http://192.168.232.151:8008/openid/
```

BODY:

```
openid.ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
openid.mode:associate
openid.assoc_type:HMAC-SHA256
openid.session_type:DH-SHA256
```

Also i tried to provide it with public key (such as openid.dh_modulus, openid.dh_gen, openid.dh_consumer_public) for Diffie-Hellman algorythm, and sniffing traffic  of OpenID authentication for get additional keys in request, but allways got 500 Internal server error
with

```
Exception Type: ProtocolError
Exception Value:    
No mode value in message <openid.message.Message {('http://openid.net/signon/1.0', u'ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0\nopenid.mode:associate\nopenid.assoc_type:HMAC-SHA256\nopenid.session_type:DH-SHA256'): u'DH-SHA256EABv%252BfEoZlgh%252BeU71rlInEppkiuX\nopenid.dh_modulus:ANz5OguIOXLsDhmYmsWizjEOHTdxfo2Vcbt2I3MYZuYe91ouJ4mLBX%2BYkcLiemOcPym2CBRYHNOyyjmG0mg3BVd9RcLn5S3IHHoXGHblzqdLFEi%2F368Ygo79JRnxTkXjgmY0rxlJ5bU1zIKaSDuKdiI%2BXUkKJX8Fvf8W8vsixYOr\nopenid.dh_gen:Ag%3D%3D\nopenid.dh_consumer_public:AJs12O5ypo2N%2FL0RJiiOgu9llg2dFsnjthyH49dx6FXz52iDXNkS7gquOm6KEr%2BUfTmktyVMA5DrZwJ%2BrX1jk7sKmXJMmi9%2B7N5fa0wvz%2Fi6nrvg8Oqw31kh%2BtbD9ansUeATSlCfUoRCqeUHEABv%2BfEoZlgh%2BeU71rlInEppkiuX'}>
```

Debugging the django-openid module I've discovered that constructing Message object raises this error but can not find values of parameters to satisfy openid-provider server

Please show me what I'm doing wrong? Am i choosing the hard way, can I use something that emulates consumer site with openid-client locally. Or maybe someone have correct example of such POST request?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best off using a publicly accessible OpenID consumer or an OpenID client library to test django-openid-provider, since constructing an OpenID request manually is inconvenient.

In the past, I've used [mod_auth_openid](http://findingscience.com/mod_auth_openid/) (an Apache module) for testing against django_openid_provider, it works well.

If you are really intent on manually providing the HTTP requests against the OpenID endpoint:

OpenID uses GET requests, not POST requests.

The parameters should be passed in the query string, not in the body.

Using [httpie](http://httpie.org), here's an example of a valid request against an OpenID provider , assuming:

- The OpenID endpoint is `http://192.168.232.151:8008/openid/`
- You've used django-openid-provider to create an openid called `myopenid`
- The OpenID consumer (relaying party) is http://www.example.com/protected/
- The OpenID consumer is protected using mod_auth_openid

Here's the initial request:

```
$ http get http://192.168.232.151:8008/openid/ \
openid.assoc_handle=={HMAC-SHA256}{42a4370e}{G804lQ====} \
openid.claimed_id==http://192.168.232.151:8008/openid/myopenid/ \
openid.identity==http://192.168.232.151:8008/openid/myopenid/ \
openid.mode==checkid_setup \
openid.ns==http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0 \
openid.realm==http://www.example.com/protected/ \
openid.return_to==http://www.example.com/protected/?modauthopenid.nonce=qAgqlNCdLl \
openid.trust_root==http://www.example.com/protected/
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$ curl http://192.168.232.151:8008/openid/?openid.assoc_handle=%7BHMAC-SHA256%7D%7B42a4370e%7D%7BG804lQ%3D%3D%3D%3D%7D&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.232.151%3A8008%2Fopenid%2Fmyopenid%2F&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.232.151%3A8008%2Fopenid%2Fmyopenid%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fprotected%2F&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fprotected%2F%3Fmodauthopenid.nonce%3DqAgqlNCdLl&openid.trust_root=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fprotected%2F
```

Note that the `openid.assoc_handle` and `modauthopenid.nonce` values are not valid in this example, you'd have to generate proper values for those.

If this succeeds, then the server should redirect you via 302 to http://www.example.com/protected/ with a number of query parameter arguments.

Also note that this is only the initial step in the protocol, there are additional requests involved.

But you really don't want to manually craft these OpenID HTTP requests. Use an OpenID library or an OpenID consumer instead.